# Convert floats to string in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

How does one create a numpy string array of N values?
For example,
I want to create a set of string like this.

```
str = ['001', ........'010',..... '365']
```

Comment: Break down your problem. Start by creating the list for your range of `1` through `365`, then use list comprehension to turn "numbers" into "formatted strings with leading zeroes as necessary".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, how can format the strings

Comment: Also note that `str` is a special symbol in Python. Name your variable something else.

Comment: `[str(n).zfill(3) for n in range(1, 366)]`

Comment: why do you want a string array? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have folders named in this sequence.

Comment: but *why do you want to use a numpy array*?

Comment: @jurez `str` is not special, just pre-defined.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for correction, I have no idea how I got this important fact mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension with string formatting to prepend zeros. If you really need in a numpy array, just wrap it in its constructor.

```
np.array([f'{i:03}' for i in range(1, 366)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do that is a list or a dictionary. The difference is that a list is simply a string array that is captured between a list [] while a dictionary also includes indexes {0:array1, 1:array2}. Depending on what works best for you you can decide and use either. Both can be edited and you can use functions such a list.append() to add elements or simply call a specific string in the array through [index].

Comment: "a list is simply a string array that is captured between a list [] " that doesn't really make much sense. A list is not "a string array", it is a *list*. And none of this really addresses the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).